# Compare new Date with date in a string in mySql format

Tags: javascript, mysql, format, compare

I have `var a = new Date()` and `var b = "21:36:40 12/01/2013`".

*a is current date*

*b is a string date* from `mySql` database in that format.

I need to :

```
If a - b > 1 year alert("old") else alert ("new").
```

I tried to split the string but it was getting to complicated..
(sorry if I did not format the code correctly)

```
            var a = new Date(); 
        var b = "21:36:40 12/01/2013"

        var c = b.split(" "); 
        var d = c[0]; 
        var e = d.split(":"); 
        var f = e[0];
        var g = e[1]; 
        var h = e[2];   
        var i = c[1]; 
        var j = i.split("/"); 
        var k = j[0]; 
        var l = j[1];
        var m = j[2]; 
        var m1 = a.getFullYear(); 
        var k1 = a.getDate(); 
        var l1 = a.getMonth(); 
        var e1 = a.getHours(); 
        var g1 = a.getMinutes();
        var h1 = a.getSeconds(); 

    function myFunction4() {
        if (m1 > m && l1 > l && k1 > k) { 
        alert("old");
        }
        else if (m1 > m && l1 == l && k1 <= 12) {
}
        alert("old");
        }   
        else {
        alert("new");
        }
    }
    myFunction4(); // incomplete
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing it by timestamp compare:

```
if (+(new Date('21:36:40 12/01/2013')) > +(new Date())){
    alert('new')
} else{
    alert('old')
}
```

Comment: This does not do what I want. I need to know if the **difference** betwen the two dates is **more than an year**.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a date object using it's constructor like so:

```
var your_date = new Date("21:36:40 12/01/2013");
var now       = new Date();
if ( now > your_date) {
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to simplify your string search/split algorithm :

```
var b = "21:36:40 12/01/2013"
var reg = /(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}) (\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/;
var dateArray = reg.exec(b); 
var dateObject = new Date(
    (+dateArray[6]),
    (+dateArray[5])-1, // Careful, month starts at 0!
    (+dateArray[4]),
    (+dateArray[1]),
    (+dateArray[2]),
    (+dateArray[3])
);
```